# Is there a way to drop multiple partitions of a BigQuery table

Tags: google-bigquery, partitioning

I want to delete multiple partitions of a bigquery table before a particular date.
I want to do this with SQL.
One way is to do it with simple query

```
delete from tablename where _partitiontime < '2021-01-01'
```

But this has a major issue of cost as it scans the data. Had it been one time this might have worked but I want to incorporate this in my project which will run periodically and for multiple tables of multiple datasets. So this won't work in my case.

DROP partition is not supported via sql. Only options are from BQ CLI or BQ API. But this only supports deleting one partition at a time. This serial process would be time taking.

Is there any alternative that fulfills this usecase?

Something like this would have solved my problem. Here the partition IDs are fetched from INFORMATION_SCHEMA. But the DROP query inside DO FOR loop is not supported by BQ.

```
FOR record IN
  (select partition_id from dataset.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARTITIONS) 
DO
  DROP dataset.table$record.partition_id; 
END FOR;
```

Comment: consider use of partition expiration!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete multiple partitions at a time, but you can use this code to delete one partition only.

```
bq rm --table project_id:dataset.table$partition
```

Meanwhile, as suggested by Mikhail, you can use [partition expiration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/managing-partitioned-tables#partition-expiration) where your partition(s) will be deleted based on the duration you will set which will start from partition boundary in UTC. Take note that the BigQuery will delete the data once the partition got deleted.

```
bq update \
--time_partitioning_expiration integer_in_seconds \
--time_partitioning_type unit_time \
project_id:dataset.table
```